# Output Group-Object Column to File

Tags: powershell, duplicates, grouping

Using Powershell I created a data set like this.

```
Count Name                      Group    
----- ----                      -----        
2 108005                    {108005, 108005} 
2 114763                    {114763, 114763}  
2 115826                    {115826, 115826}     
2 115925                    {115925, 115925}    
2 117435                    {117435, 117435}    
2 114152                    {114152, 114152}   
2 117093                    {117093, 117093}
```

Using this code.

```
$check = Get-Content $file | Group | Where {$_.count -gt 1}
```

I used the code to check for duplicates and cannot figure out how to output the Name column to a list in a plain txt file with only the names. There doesn't seem to be much documentation on how to do this. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either `ForEach-Object` or `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`:

```
$duplicates = Get-Content $file | Group | Where {$_.count -gt 1} |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Since you don't need anything other than the name, you can avoid generating the individual sets during grouping, with the `-NoElement` switch parameter:

```
$duplicates = Get-Content $file | Group -NoElement | Where {$_.count -gt 1} |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```